# SSAS Create dynamic measures from values in dimension

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap-cube

I have a cube where I need to create dynamic measures using the script command. 
the data is like the below:

```
Dim_Market  Dim_Target  value
Martket1    target1     val1
Martket1    target2     val1
Martket1    target3     val1
Martket2    target2     val1
Martket2    target1     val1
Martket2    target2     val1
```

The newly created measures should be like the below:

- Martket1_Target1
- Martket1_Target2
- Martket1_Target3
- ...

Is there anyway to do this? The values in the dimensions are not static so we can't create the columns in the datasource view.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
[Dim_Market].[Martket].CurrentMember.Name + "_" + [Dim_Target].[Target].CurrentMember.Name
```

?

Comment: I need the values to be created like this but for all the items dynamically. some sort of "for each" loop